# How can I move the WordPress toolbar CODE to the top of the page?

Tags: wordpress

Before anyone says this may be a duplicate, I don't want to move the toolbar to the bottom of the page with css.  I have a layout that is being fudged up by the toolbar.  The toolbar is covering the top of my banner.  I want to move the code for the toolbar from the bottom of the HTML to the top and then change the position to relative instead of fixed.  This way the toolbar will push all the content after it down instead of covering up the content.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add this to your `functions.php` file so that the Admin bar is no longer rendered on the `wp_footer` action:

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
```

After you do this, just add this in your `header.php` file right after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<?php wp_admin_bar_render(); ?>
```

Also find the opening `<html>` tag in the same file and add `class="html_class"`. This will allow us to override the margin-top that WordPress adds to the html element.

Then write the CSS necessary to make the admin bar stationary:

```
#wpadminbar {
    position: relative !important;
}
html.html_class {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is working as it should so far, but apparently WP adds a margin to the top of the body that's the height of the adminbar.  Is there any way I can remove this? * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 - I updated my answer. Basically the solution is to add a custom class to your `html` tag and use that to override the inline CSS that WordPress adds. There could be another way actually(where the inline CSS just doesn't render), but I haven't looked into whether it's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

The top bar often seems to do this. Why not just get rid of it?  That's what I usually do.

In functions.php add the following:

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```